# JLabel with Image won't erase from the screen

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have an array of Jlabels and each has an imageIcon attached to it. the attachment is happening outside the constructor in a method that is been called several times and at the end of the method i use repaint().

the problem is, that after a certin Jlabel has been draw, i can't make him to "unDraw, even if i change the Jlabel (or the image) to null. is seems to just stay there.

i tried to repaint again, to reset the background color and to revalidate, and non seems to do the job.

any ideas?

**EDIT**: i tried the following (inside the edt) and it seems to only change the last JLable on the array:

```
for (int j = 0;j<playerCards.length;j++){
    remove(playerCards[j]);
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong and since you didn't post your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem we can't help. The setIcon() method will work. You don't even need to use repaint() because the label is smart enough to repaint itself when one of its properties is changed.

Comment: Did you use `remove()` on the parent container?  I don't know what it means to change a `JLabel` to `null`; if you say, for instance, `JLabel[] arr;` and later `arr[i] = null;`, that has no effect on the GUI (I don't know of any Swing components that would care about your `JLabel[]` array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your UI operations into the EDT thread.  Not making them in there can lead to unpredictable results.

**EDT - Event Dispatch Thread**

You should use the EDT thread to make changes to GUI so that this is the only thread that makes changes to it.

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //UI changes here
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: is it necesery even if i do all the oporations on the main thread?

Comment: Yes because any other updates done by any other thread other than your own (including that of the EDT which may well be doing stuff you dont know about) would be from a second thread so it's better to just do all your UI adjustments in that thread also.

Comment: @SaharZehavi,  define "main thread". If you are executing your code from a listener, then that code executes on the EDT automatically. If you are creating a custom Thread then you need to use invokeLater(). Your question is so vague it is hard to answer, that is why you need to post a SSCCE.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(YOUR_OBJECT_CONTAINER);
```

where YOUR_OBJECT_CONTAINER is a java object that extends JComponent that contains the JLabel you want to remove.

Comment: -1, this is not an appropriate suggestion. The method is used for a LAF change. Swing components are smart enough to repaint themselves when a property has been changed.